# Apple Watch, keep calendar-details during entire meeting

Tags: calendar, apple-watch

I mostly use the "modules" watch face since I can have my next meeting in the middle. However I noticed now that the current appointment I have will disappear and show the the next appointment before the current one has actually ended. This is a big problem for me since it is very important I always know when my current meeting ends so I can close it in the right time.

See the image below, the "J4" meeting will be removed from the watch face before 10:50. I want it to stay until 10:50 or at least 10:45. Is that possible?

[image: watch face]

Comment: You say that the 10:30 to 10:50 meeting was removed before 10:50. When did the meeting after that start, according to your calendar? If it started before 10:50, say at 10:40, it will be the event to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Apple Watch calendar]

Hmm, that's wierd, it's OK for me.

Try these:

- check if WatchOS is latest version
- check if your calendar is synced with the end-date in your iPhone / iCloud Calendar.

For me it works without any hassle.

p.s. This is added through iCloud / iPhone, not a remote calendar, might be that.